# Android - How to dynamically change text when a certain sensor is triggered

Tags: android

This is my code for the onSensorChanged thus far:

```
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
            dynamictext.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + " MS^-2 \nY: " + event.values[1] + " MS^-2 \nZ: " + event.values[2] + " MS^-2");
        } else if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR).size() != 0) {
            dynamictext.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2] + "scalar: " + event.values[3]);}
```

As you can see I was checking if the sensor existed in the sensor list then update dynamictext, however this is not my intention.

The intention is to only update this text when the Sensor that is triggered is triggered. written in Psuedo this would be like this for example:

if(AccelerometerSensorWasTriggered == accelerometer){
     Run code}

I tried:

```
if(this == TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){}
```

Note: HandlerThread is used for my sensors so I can actually set the dynamic text.

I kind of think that I need to pass in event? Any clarification or any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need to pass any event as this method is called automatically

make sure that you have added these lines:

```
s = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

this is my code where I change the textview, you will get an idea:

```
package com.example.accel_dialer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.NoCopySpan.Concrete;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AccelDialActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    SensorManager sm;
    Sensor s;
    Context cv = this;
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4,tv5,tv6;
    double a, min = 20,max=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accel_dial);
        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        s = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.max);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float ax, ay, az;

        ax = event.values[0];
        ay = event.values[1];
        az = event.values[2];
        a = Math.sqrt((ax * ax) + (ay * ay) + (az * az));
        if(a<min)
        {
            min=a;
        }
        if(a>max)
        {
            max=a;
        }

        tv1.setText("AX:" + ax);
        tv2.setText("Ay:" + ay);
        tv3.setText("Az:" + az);
        tv4.setText("A:" + a);
        tv5.setText(""+min);
        tv6.setText(""+max);
        if(a>40)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:any contact number"));
            cv.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Savagefool you are welome